# Can "since" and "for" be used interchangeably?

Tags: word-choice

Example:

> I had no idea how deep the forest really was, though the people around
>   often used the word endless to describe it. And I believed that was
>   the case, **for** I'd never seen the end of it, not even
>   standing from the tallest balcony.

Will the meaning change if I use *since*, instead? I'm not sure why, but I feel using *for* will make the passage sound a bit "dated"?

Comment: The choice between *for*, *since* and *as* depends entirely upon the rest of the content, whether it is formal or informal, and if literary or not. *Since* is overly formal, *as* is always a convenient option, *for* is literary. In the example case, use of a direct *because* would be helping the reader a bit.

Comment: It's perhaps better to say something like 'dated' rather than 'old English'. 'Old English' is the earliest form of the language, sometimes known as 'Anglo-Saxon'.

Comment: @Barrie England Thanks, that was the word I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, yes, they may be used interchangeably. I agree that "for" sounds a bit old-fashioned, but as a personal preference, I would use "as" instead - it seems to flow more rhythmically, and all three share "because" as a possible definition.

"And I believed that was the case, as I'd never seen the end of it, not even standing from the tallest balcony."

Comment: I think that in this case *for* is less "old-fashioned" than "literary", and I think it works better here than either *as* or *since*. (When I read just the one sentence, *as* sounds fine, but when I read the whole thing, I like *for* better. Though I'm sure that's subjective.)

Comment: I prefer "for" as well, but if OP is really adamant about replacing it, I think "since" is possibly the least appealing option.

Answer (score 0):

When used in a purely time related context it may not work. Couple of examples:

> I hadn't done this since high-school.

"For" doesn't work for this sentence.

> I haven't been able to enjoy coffee since I quit smoking.

Acceptable.

> I cannot study since there is no electricity.

Perfectly interchangeable.

As you see, it greatly depends on the context but using "for" when applicable will add variety. And it sounds cooler as far as I'm concerned :)